# AG Grid full row edit validation

Tags: typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to validate all cells before stop editing. For example;

```
---Header1---   | ---Header2---  |  ---Header3---   
     1          |      2         |       3
```

Let say all of the values should be 6 in total. If I change header1's value to 2, and change header3's value to 2, they will be 6 in total again. However, I could not reach the latest the header1's value, when I get header1's value, it is still 1 due to editing mode. But I cant stop editing mode since I will stop it after validation and saving the data to backend. If I stop editing, then even I didnt save, values will be stay even validation error.

How can I get the edited value before stopping editing mode on ag grid?

Thank you!

Comment: Did ever found a solution to this one without accessing the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the grid is in **fullRowEdit** Mode, in case of **cellEditMode** you can easily get the updated value once you tab-out from the cell in the next cell.

For **fullRowEdit Mode** to get the current value there is no event given by ag grid before stopEditing() is called I can only think of one way  -  **access the value directly from DOM**

1. get the  current editing row  dom
2. then check the dom element
3. pass the index of appropriate ag-cell index (column no)

below code  will help you to understand it clearly

let's say you want to calculate on focus out, so in the cell renderer

```
    focusOut = function () {
        let intialQuerSelctorString = `div.ag-row[row- 
        index='${this.params.rowIndex.toString()}']` ; //get the  current editing row  dom


        let editedValue  =  document.querySelectorAll(intialQuerSelctorString) 
       [1].querySelectorAll("div.ag-cell")[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

 // then check the dom element pass the index of appropriate div.ag-cell index (column no)
    };
```

or else the angular way will be

```
<div #gridId><ag-grid></ag-grid> </div>
  @ViewChild('gridId', { read: ElementRef, static: true }) gridId: ElementRef;
```

then fetch the dom values from row index and column index.